# Is it possible to have only one TableTools with multiple tables?

Tags: jquery, sql, datatables, tabletools

I'm trying to generate a page with 4 different result sets. This data will be displayed using DataTables.

I was wondering...
Is it possible to have only one TableTools with multiple tables? (I couldn't find this info anywhere)

What I'm trying to get is to display 4 tables, with different result sets and have the option with TableTools to export everything to either CSV, Excel or PDF.

Is it possible or am I asking too much?

Thanks in advance!

Fede

Comment: only one tabletools toolbar, so I can export all tables on one single file. Instead of having one export toolbar per table.

Comment: I feel sure this is possible but will be tricky. You may well have to build a custom toolbar mimicking the standard toolbar. The custom CSV, Excel and PDF buttons will need to build a new (hidden) composite table dynamically from your four result sets, then invoke DataTables and TableTools on the new table, then trigger the corresponding real CSV, Excel or PDF button. It's about a day's work.

Comment: Same requirement. Have you found any solution?